# Gravar em duas ou mais tabelas MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

Fazer isso com dois ou mais inserts separados na mesma função é simples, mas existe alguma maneira mais correta e que consuma a menor quantidade de recursos ? Na plataforma que estamos trabalhando, todas as ações do usuários serão gravadas em outras tabelas para posteriormente gerar estatísticas.

Comment: Desconheço alguma forma nativa disso, já que isso não é responsabilidade do banco, sim da aplicação gerenciar os logs de user. O MySQL tem alternativas para gerar logs de querys, que é inviável as vezes. Única forma que me vem a cabeça é responsabilidade da aplicação.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488267/how-to-log-user-actions-with-php-and-mysql

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33654/mysql-logging-activity-from-specific-user-or-ip

Comment: também desconheço uma maneira de fazer sem que seja com vários inserts, você pode analisar qual é melhor opção pra gravar, pode armazenar em sessões e de tempo em tempo gravar no banco.

Comment: Posso gravar em um arquivo de .txt e de com o tempo atualizar... acho que é a melhor opção então...

Answer (score 0):

Não sei qual linguagem você está habituado a trabalhar, mas você poderia gravar cada um dos eventos em uma sessão (SESSIONS) armazenando a **id** do executor dos eventos, e definir um tempo de salvamento para gravar o pacote de eventos, através de um script com agendador do tipo **crontab**. Como também poderia criar uma *procedure* (rotina) que execute um script no MySQL.

Para criar uma *procedure* e executar um script de eventos, confira abaixo:

1. [**Agendar eventos do MySQL**](//dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html)
2. [**Criar rotinas no MySQL**](//dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-procedure.html)

Comment: Uso PHP, as sessions não tornam lento? inicialmente pensei em adicionar informações em .txt e processar uma vez ao dia.... não é bom ?

Comment: sessions não são lentas.

Comment: Pode gerar um log.txt também, é uma opção, porém você pode ter problemas com memória da mesma forma que envia para o mysql. A diferença é pequena.

Comment: se não quer usar session, use cookie, ou serialize seus dados para ocupar espaço.

Comment: Então session gasta menos memoria que gravar um log.txt correto? entendi.

Comment: Sim. Porque é memória de execução.

Comment: Se pode criar txt, também pode criar planilhas csv, que é mais indicado para importação.

Comment: Também poderia usar Lucene do apache.

Comment: usando session é server-side, cookie é client-side.

Comment: Para ter certeza de qual processo toma mais recursos, basta criar um método de teste de consumo de memória e performance como o: https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind

Comment: É mas to vendo aqui, acho que session não é o ideal, preciso recuperar todas as session no final e gravar no baco de dados, no fim do dia... e como faria isso? a session é do usuário e não adiciona informações apenas sobrescreve....